# Paint swing Component to Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

How do I paint a Component, like a JPanel, into a Graphics of my choice,
as if it were teh screen?

Had no luck on google.

What I have tried:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setSize(32, 32);
p.setLocation(8, 8);

p.add(new JLabel(...));
p.add(new JLabel(...));
p.add(new ImageIcon(...));

Graphics g = getSomeGraphics();
p.paint(g);
```

however, this last instruction causes

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.getVolatileOffscreenBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Comment: This answer might help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506485/jpanel-not-displaying-in-jframe-after-paint-is-called/14508757#14508757

Comment: How are you getting the `Graphics`?  Generally one would use a `BufferedImage` for this type of thing, and paint onto that (using its `Graphics`).  I assume you're basically trying to paint a component into an image, although I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Chances are you're using `getGraphics` - don't do this. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966134/java-2d-api-null-pointer-exception/14966445#14966445)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing : Obtain \`Image\` of JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

Comment: Not a JFrame, just a Component! I must paint only teh JPanel, not teh whole Frame. And you could assume that I'm drawing into a BufferedImage, which I do sometimes, in fact.

Comment: You mean for example draw a rectangle on JPanel ?

Comment: Unless the component is realised on the screen, use printAll instead. Calling paint assumes that the component is, on one way, attached to a native peer

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513) illustrates using `panel.paint(g2d)` to render an existing `JPanel` of `JLabel` instances in a `BufferedImage`. The image is then scaled and displayed below the panel for reference.

[image]

Comment: I just realized this works the same way as @Andrew's [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/230513).

Comment: And what if I can't make a JFrame to put my component into?

Comment: Your example works because it add() teh Component to another Container, a JPanel, but, in my app, I have no JFrame(), nor any other Container.

Comment: @camickr's [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15035642/230513) may work in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> And you could assume that I'm drawing into a BufferedImage, which I do sometimes, in fact.

See [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/), which can also create a component image.